# Connecting remotely from Ubuntu to another linux

Tags: 12.04, ssh, remote-access, sshd

I want to connect remotely from Ubuntu to Suse. Two different systems in two different locations. I know how to use ssh to connect remotely to a machine in the same network. But, I do not know how to connect machines from two different locations.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have problems with closed source, you can use [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com).

**To download for ubuntu:**
64bit from [here](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux_x64.deb)
32bit from [here](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb)

**To download for SUSE:**
From [here](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.rpm)

---

If both systems have real IPs ot lay on the same network you have chunk of options like VNC, XRDP, X11RDP, Nomachine NX, FreeNx and many others

Comment: ssh 192.168.10.8 -l ali-ubuntu
ali-ubuntu@192.168.10.8's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: what is this password?